# Valid html tag to group definition list items

Tags: html, xhtml

I currently have:

```
<dl>

  <span class="wrapper">

    <dt>A title</dt>
    <dd>A description</dd>

  </span>

  <span class="wrapper">

    <dt>A title</dt>
    <dd>A description</dd>

  </span>

</dl>
```

This (or divs instead of spans) doesn't validate. Is there anything I could wrap it with that would?

Comment: There have been proposals for <di> - definition item - that would have done exactly what you want, but it remained just a proposal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A `dl` allows only two kinds of children: `dt` and `dd`. See this article for a [longer explanation](http://www.benmeadowcroft.com/webdev/articles/definition-lists/).

In short: the reason why `dt` and `dd` aren't "grouped" is that you can have one *or more* `dt` elements per `dd`.

If you really need to group, then your only option is to build the list manually using `<ul>`/`<ol>` with the necessary CSS.

Comment: or viceversa, you can have one or more `dd` elements per `dt`. I still think a <di> element would work great for wrapping a group of `dt` and `dd` that are related, no matter how many of them there are...

Comment: If you build a list manually please use some list element like `ul` or `ol`. I don't think that falling back to `div`s is appropriate here.

Comment: @inta: I kind of agree even through it makes the CSS more complex. Updated my answer.

Comment: Offering something like a `di` wouldn't restrict the option to have multiple `dt`/`dd` elements. I don't really understand why is not included in the spec.

Answer (score 3):

**2022 update:**

The accepted answer is quite old and outdated.

According to the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), you can actually use a `<div>` to group `<dt>` and `<dd>`:

> The `dl` element represents an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list). A name-value group consists of one or more names (`dt` elements, possibly as children of a div element child) followed by one or more values (`dd` elements, possibly as children of a `div` element child), ignoring any nodes other than `dt` and `dd` element children, and `dt` and `dd` elements that are children of `div` element children. Within a single `dl` element, there should not be more than one `dt` element for each name.
>
> ...
>
> In order to annotate groups with microdata attributes, or other global attributes that apply to whole groups, or just for styling purposes, each group in a `dl` element can be wrapped in a `div` element. This does not change the semantics of the `dl` element.

So your HTML snippet is almost right, just replace the `<span>`s with `<div>`s:

```css
dl {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding: 8px;
}

dt {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  padding: 8px;
}

dd {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)
}

.wrapper  + .wrapper  {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<dl>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <dt>A title</dt>
    <dd>A description</dd>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <dt>A title</dt>
    <dd>A description</dd>
  </div>
  
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "group" them. They are grouped by virtue of their relative positions in the `<dl>`. In HTML, the next-sibling relationship is a strong one.